# Get all values in temp table with sql pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this data at temp table

```
Country    |City
-----------|-------------
Philippines|Mandaluyong
Philippines|Quezon
Philippines|Aurora
America    |Example
America    |Example2
```

And I want to display using pivot like this

```
Philippines|America
-----------|-------------
Aurora     |Example
Mandaluyong|Example2
Quezon
```

But currently, I got this only

```
Philippines|America
-----------|-------------
Quezon|Example2
```

Here is my code below. Did I miss something?

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (Country VARCHAR(MAX), City VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @TempTable (Country, City)
SELECT  'Philippines' AS Country, 'Mandaluyong' AS City
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Philippines', 'Quezon'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Philippines', 'Aurora'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'America', 'Example'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'America', 'Example2'

SELECT * FROM @TempTable

SELECT Philippines, America
FROM
(
SELECT Country, city
FROM @TempTable 
)temp
PIVOT
(
MAX (City)
For Country in (Philippines, America)
)piv
```

Comment: FYI there is a code format button in the question editor - makes it *much* easier to read.

Comment: thanks, im new to this. thanks for guiding me

Comment: Please explain the logic for your required output.

Comment: @mkRabbani I already said that "And i want to display using pivot like this"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result set was grouping by the Country field, as a result there would be one row per Country, which is what gave the results the way you have.

On including a grouping column (ie numbering the records by country in a row_number) function you would get the results you expect

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (Country VARCHAR(MAX), City VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @TempTable (Country, City)
SELECT  'Philippines' AS Country, 'Mandaluyong' AS City
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Philippines', 'Quezon'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Philippines', 'Aurora'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'America', 'Example'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'America', 'Example2'

SELECT * FROM @TempTable

SELECT Philippines, America
FROM
(
SELECT row_number() over(partition by Country order by city) as rnk,Country, city
FROM @TempTable
WHERE country in ('Philippines','America')
)temp
PIVOT
(
MAX (City)
For Country in (Philippines, America)
)piv
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=212381456098cd4fd858de3e01257067